# adding characters using charAt in java is giving me the wrong sum

Tags: java, string

```
int x=(int)compressedText.charAt(one1+1);
int y=(int)compressedText.charAt(one1+2);
count=x+y;
count1=(char)count;
```

the craracter value for    compressedText.charAt(one1+2) and compressedText.charAt(one1+1) are  each equal to 1 but when I try to debug my code it says count is equal to 98.

Comment: The `char` `1` is equal to the `int` `49` - see [here](http://www.scism.lsbu.ac.uk/jfl/Appa/appa4.html). A `char` represents an Unicode character.

Answer (score 3):

Casting a `char` that represents a numeric *character* to an `int` doesn't do what you think it does.  It takes the Unicode value of the `char` (which is `49` for `'1'`).  That explains why you get `98` instead of `2`.

Because the code values for the characters `'0'` through `'9'` are `48` through `57`, you can subtract `'0'` (`48`) from each `char` instead, e.g.

```
int x = compressedText.charAt(one1+1) - '0';
```

You'll need to undo this conversion if you are converting an `int` back to a `char` that is meant to represent the numeric character.  Also you'll need to account for multiple characters if `count` is more than one digit (>= 10).

Comment: Wouldn't [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) work as well?